# Is JavaScript eval() function safe to use for numeric operations?

Tags: javascript, security, eval, calculator

Please check the code below first.

```
const plusFn = function(){
  const sign = '+'
  inputUser.textContent += sign

  const equalFn = function(){
    const input = `${inputUser.value}`
    const numbers = input.split(`${sign}`)
    const result = eval(`${+numbers[0]}${sign}${+numbers[1]}`)
  }
  btnEqual.addEventListener('click',equalFn)
}

btnPlus.addEventListener('click',plusFn)
```

Let's assume our user pressed 123 and wrote it to input area, then pressed +, from now on he trigerred the plusFn which determines a specific operator and adding a new event listener for equality button. When he gives second number and presses the equality button, operating will work as upside. Is it safe to use like that?

Comment: It's a matter of (highly-charged) opinion. What isn't a matter of opinion is that you **must not** use input from user A in code you're running in user B's environment via `eval`, because it allows arbitrary code execution.

Comment: "but I couldn't think any alternative" > You could google for "basic calculator javascript" to find an alternative. This has already been done multiple times, so I doubt you will get an answer here

Comment: if you're implementing this in javascript also watch out for float precision funkiness like `0.1 + 0.2` which yields `0.30000000000000004`

Comment: @Binary yeah, I think I can escape from this weird behaviour by using Math.trunc() or toFixed() , but for doing this firstly I have to get a number from my functions :)

Comment: Yes, it is doable, and you don't risk having to sell your heck out to be forgiven by the coding community. It's just that the use of an eval will not allow you to obtain a mastery of the calculation and will sometimes give you abhorrent results, as Binary indicates to you in its comment.

Comment: @MisterJojo Oh okay, I guess google for some examples will be better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> but I couldn't think any alternative

For something as simple as your example, where you have exactly two inputs and an operator from a constrained list (just `+` in your example, but I'm guessing you have three others), you could use a dispatcher object or `Map`:

```
const operatons = {
    "+": (a, b) => a + b,
    "*": (a, b) => a * b,
    "/": (a, b) => a / b,
    // ...
};
// Using it...
const operation = operation[operator];
if (!operation) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid operator "${operator}"`);
}
const result = operation(input1, input2);
```